# Setting the fmt option in numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, save

I am looking at the `numpy.savetxt`, and am stuck at the `fmt` option.

I tried looking at [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) and also the reference in the link below all the letters that can be used for the `fmt` option sort give me a general sense of what is going on.

What I do not understand is if the `%` symbol is required and in an example given [here](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#id2) how should I interpret the 10.5 number? 
If "f" is about setting the floating point, then how come is it 10.5 (then again, I might not know how floating points are set...).

Comment: the 10 and 5 in %10.5f are described by points 4. and 5. in the docs you first link to.

Comment: Silly me... Thanks for that ! I did not realize that those points were actually answers to my question until you pointed them out ! So field with in this case is just [like in here](https://sites.google.com/site/mrdelaneysweb/python-field-widths). That's quite neat!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Knowing that [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) only works for 1D or 2D arrays, the general idea is:

- when `fmt` is a single formatting string it applies to all elements in the 
  array (1D or 2D input array)
- when `fmt` is a sequence of formatting strings, it applies to each column of the 2D input array

I'm presenting here some examples using the following input array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14],
              [21, 22, 23, 24],
              [31, 32, 33, 34]])
```

1) Setting floating point precision: `np.savetxt('tmp.txt', a, fmt='%1.3f')`

```
11.000 12.000 13.000 14.000
21.000 22.000 23.000 24.000
31.000 32.000 33.000 34.000
```

2) Adding characters to right-justify.

With spaces: `np.savetxt('tmp.txt', a, fmt='% 4d')`

```
  11   12   13   14
  21   22   23   24
  31   32   33   34
```

With zeros: `np.savetxt('tmp.txt', a, fmt='%04d')`

```
0011 0012 0013 0014
0021 0022 0023 0024
0031 0032 0033 0034
```

3) Adding characters to left-justify (use of "`-`").

With spaces: `np.savetxt('tmp.txt', a, fmt='%-4d')`

```
11   12   13   14  
21   22   23   24  
31   32   33   34
```

4) When `fmt` is a sequence of formatting strings, each row of a 2D input array is processed according to `fmt`:

`fmt` as a **sequence in a single formatting string**

```
fmt = '%1.1f + %1.1f / (%1.1f * %1.1f)'
np.savetxt('tmp.txt', a, fmt=fmt)

11.0 + 12.0 / (13.0 * 14.0)
21.0 + 22.0 / (23.0 * 24.0)
31.0 + 32.0 / (33.0 * 34.0)
```

`fmt` as an **iterator of formatting strings**:

```
fmt = '%d', '%1.1f', '%1.9f', '%1.9f'
np.savetxt('tmp.txt', a, fmt=fmt)

11 12.0 13.000000000 14.000000000
21 22.0 23.000000000 24.000000000
31 32.0 33.000000000 34.000000000
```

Answer (score 7):

This [link](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) might be helpful.

From the link:

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
fill        ::=  <any character>
align       ::=  "<" | ">" | "=" | "^"
sign        ::=  "+" | "-" | " "
width       ::=  integer
precision   ::=  integer
type        ::=  "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "E" | "f" | "F" | "g" | "G" | "n" | "o" | "s" | "x" | "X" | "%"
```

> Width is a decimal integer defining the minimum field width. If not specified, then the field width will be determined by the content.
>
> When no explicit alignment is given, preceding the width field by a zero ('0') character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a fill character of '0' with an alignment type of '='.
>
> The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'f' and 'F', or before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'g' or 'G'. For non-number types the field indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters will be used from the field content. The precision is not allowed for integer values.