# How to write several variables with the same format in a line to the file?

Tags: python, format

I have a matrix named `t`. I want to write it into a text file row by row. Also, each element in the matrix has a same format, for example `10.3f`. The problem is that each row has 48 elements that I cannot write explicitly.

I tried to use `{f}*{}`:

```py
for i in range(len(t[0][:])) :
    result.write( "'{8.3f}'*{per}\n".format( t[:][i],per=len(t[:][i]) ) )
```

I got the error as follow:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the fmt option in numpy.savetxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043393/setting-the-fmt-option-in-numpy-savetxt)

Comment: why don't you use nested loop - ie. `for row in t: for item in row: ...`.

Comment: Why are you using `t[:][i]` rather than just `t[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although using [[Scipy.Docs]: **numpy.savetxt**(*fname, X, fmt='%.18e', delimiter=' ', newline='\n', header='', footer='', comments='# ', encoding=None*)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) would be the recommended way, it's also possible using *Python* formatting. Note that I assumed it's an *NumPy* array because of pieces of code like `len(t[:][i])`, but the code will work the same for a *Python* matrix as well.

Referencing [[Python 3.Docs]: string - Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

There are 3 problems:

- Missing a colon ("***:***") in the float format specifier
- "*******" from inside the string format is just what it is, a string, and doesn't do what you want (multiplying the previous part). In order to do that, you must take it out of the format
- The sequence argument must be unpacked ([[Python 3.Docs]: More Control Flow Tools - Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists))

Example (I also cleaned your code a bit):

> ```py
> >>> import sys
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>>
> >>> t = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
> >>>
> >>> result = sys.stdout  # Use stdout to mimic file write
> >>>
> >>> for line in t:
> ...     result.write(("{:8.3f}" * len(line) + "\n").format(*line))
> ...
>    1.000   2.000   3.000   4.000
> 33
>    5.000   6.000   7.000   8.000   9.000
> 41
> ```

**Note**: The 2 unwanted lines in the output, are `result.write`'s return value (number of written *char*s) which gets automatically printed.

Comment: This works perfect for me. Also I want to mention that using ( ("{:8.3f}" * "{per}" + "\n")).format(*t, per=len(t) ) causes a problem, because "{per}" return a string that cannot be multiplied.

Comment: That's true. You can't change the string format from itself. The format is final at the moment you are passing the variables to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track—and here's how to make that work:

```
import sys

result = sys.stdout

t = [[3, 1.2, 3.45, 6.789],
     [863.202, 730.2, 833.67]]

for row in t:
    fmtspec = '{:8.3f}' * len(row)
    result.write(fmtspec.format(*row) + '\n')
```

Output:

```
   3.000   1.200   3.450   6.789
 863.202 730.200 833.670
```

If all the rows are the same length, you only need to create the formatting specification once:

```
t2 = [[3, 1.2, 3.45, 6.789],
     [863.202, 730.2, 833.67, 23.1456]]

fmtspec = '{:8.3f}' * len(t2[0])  # Use length of first row.
for row in t2:
    result.write(fmtspec.format(*row) + '\n')
```

```
   3.000   1.200   3.450   6.789
 863.202 730.200 833.670  23.146
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) if applicable.

Other option would be similar to previously given:

```
import os
FORMAT = "{:10.3f}"

t = [ [123, 1.2, 3.45, 6.789],
    [3863.202, 730.2, 833.67],
    [863.202, 7230.2, 833.67], ]

def numbers_to_line(*args):
    template = FORMAT * len(args) + os.linesep
    return template.format(*args)

with open("result.txt", "w") as fh:
    for row in t:
        fh.write(numbers_to_line(*row))
```

and the output:

```
   123.000     1.200     3.450     6.789
  3863.202   730.200   833.670
   863.202  7230.200   833.670
```