# python print FMT instead of saving to a file

Tags: python-3.x, printing, save, prediction

i have a python code for predicting machine learning nlp the below code used for prediction

by text file but i modified to get the input form terminal instead of reading file

and now i want to see the output instead save it to the file

i did not understand or how to use **fmt=%**

**code:**

```
for prediction in predictions:
    print('16')
    print(type(prediction))
    # sequence = ' '.join([y_ix_to_word[index] for index in prediction if index > 0])
    sequence = ' '.join([y_ix_to_word[index] for index in prediction if index > 0])

    print('17')
    print(sequence)
    print('18')
    sequences.append(sequence)
    print('19')
    print('20')
    print(sequences)
    print(type(sequences))
np.savetxt('test_result.txt', sequences, fmt='%s')
```

i looked at  [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043393/setting-the-fmt-option-in-numpy-savetxt)

i just want make a print instead of save to a file